# SQLException: "The table is full" during SonarQube 6.7 LTS upgrade

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, database-migration

We've been using SonarQube for a long time, upgraded over many versions and now executed the long awaited LTS upgrade from version 5.6.6 to 6.7. Unfortunately, the database migration failed due to an SQLException "The table 'project_measures' is full".

Are there any guidelines about what do in such a case?

Is it not okay to upgrade directly from version 5.6.6 to 6.7? Should I first upgrade to some other intermediate version? I thought LTS-to-LTS upgrades should work out fine...

```
2017.11.15 00:49:38 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1218 'Delete orphan measures without component': success | time=16143ms
2017.11.15 00:49:38 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1219 'Make column PROJECT_MEASURES.COMPONENT_UUID not nullable'...
2017.11.15 00:51:04 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] #1219 'Make column PROJECT_MEASURES.COMPONENT_UUID not nullable': failure | time=85651ms
2017.11.15 00:51:04 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] Executed DB migrations: failure | time=1502042ms
2017.11.15 00:51:04 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration failed | time=1502119ms
2017.11.15 00:51:04 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration ended with an exception
org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepExecutionException: Execution of migration step #1219 'Make column PROJECT_MEASURES.COMPONENT_UUID not nullable' failed
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:79)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:67)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:590)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.engine.MigrationEngineImpl.execute(MigrationEngineImpl.java:50)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doUpgradeDb(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:105)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doDatabaseMigration(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute ALTER TABLE project_measures MODIFY COLUMN component_uuid VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:97)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:77)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:117)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.version.v60.MakeComponentUuidNotNullOnMeasures.execute(MakeComponentUuidNotNullOnMeasures.java:40)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange.execute(DdlChange.java:45)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:75)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The table 'project_measures' is full
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2444)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:82)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

SonarQube is installed on a RHEL7 host using MySQL (rh-mysql57-mysql-server). The database location is `/var/opt/rh/rh-mysql57/lib/mysql/sonar` and there is free disk space available (but maybe not enough?):

```
/dev/mapper/vg0-var_opt   20G   17G  3.1G  85% /var/opt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade 5.6.6 to 6.7 is supported. According to your stack trace you are using MySQL server.

Can you have a look at server log files and the free space available on MySQL (maybe there is no enough space on your MySQL server for the migration) ?

Comment: Although 3G of space was still available, this did not seem to be enough for the migration. I have now increased the partition by 20G and the migration seems to be continuing from the point it previously crashed...